# Hibernate java 10

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I migrated my application from java 8 to java 10. 
But now I see the following exception when try to store something in a database

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
... 91 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Exception releasing cache locks
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$AfterTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.afterTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.afterTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:513) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2501) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.afterTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:479) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$400(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
... 91 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.delegate accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.reflect" to unnamed module @55283c54
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:337) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:281) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:176) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:170) ~[?:?]
```

I use the following dependencies

```
<spring.version>4.3.18.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring-boot.version>1.5.14.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
<hibernate-core.version>5.3.2.Final</hibernate-core.version>
<java.version>1.10</java.version>
```

Comment: Try to add `--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED` to your JVM args.

Comment: @RobertHume I'll try it

Comment: @RobertHume It's help me, but I got other problem
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field final jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.ucp accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module

What do you think about it?

Comment: @ИванГладуш you need to duplicate that `--add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED` for all such modules (replacing `jdk.internal.reflect` with applicable module)

Comment: @Ivan TY You make my day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the root cause

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.delegate accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.reflect" to unnamed module @55283c54
```

Java 10 has concept of modules and first of all `public` is not "that" public anymore and reflection is also not that powerful.

You could use JVM flag as suggested by @RobertHume but in fact you need to migrate to a newer Hibernate version that supports Java9/10 (if any).

Also check this link https://www.sitepoint.com/reflection-vs-encapsulation-in-the-java-module-system/#commandlineescapehatches for more details regarding suggested JVM flag

Comment: @ИванГладуш, would be good if you also take this to Hibernate devs. I bet they'd like to know that this happens.